# Last digit of a repeating period

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In a collection of number theory problems, I found this one:

> Give the last digit of the decimal period of $$\frac{133}{7^{88}}$$

After we start simplfying to
$$\frac{19}{7^{87}}$$
I don't know what else to do. I do know that the period will be of $6\times7^{86}$ digits long, so it is infeasible to compute in the near(and very likely to be far) future with brute force. [Midy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midy%27s_theorem) does not help too much either. What to do next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\gcd (p,10) = 1$, consider the fraction $\frac{1}{p} = 0. \overline{a_1 a_2\ldots a_n}$. What can you say about $p \times \overline{a_1 a_2\ldots a_n}$?

> $p \times \overline{a_1 a_2\ldots a_n} = 10^n -1$

In particular, what is $p \times a_n \equiv \pmod{10}$?

> $p \times a_n \equiv  9 \pmod{10}$

Now substitute $p = 7^{87}$. What is $a_n$? (You might find it useful to apply Euler's Theorem, which states that $7^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$.

> $7^{87} a_n \equiv  9 \Rightarrow a_n \equiv 3 \pmod{10}$

Now, what is the last digit in $\frac{19}{7^{87}}$?

> It is the last digit of $19 \times 3 \equiv 7 \pmod{10}$.

---

Note: A similar procedure allows you to find the last $k$ digits.

Comment: I get what you mean, but I cant see why this helps.

Comment: @chubakueno What would take the place of ??

Comment: $9$, but how do I proceed then?

Comment: @chubakueno I added the rest of the steps

Comment: I can't believe that the answer was right in front of me. I was thinking of all sort of things except solving for $a_n$. Thanks.

Comment: @chubakueno yea, if you knew about the period, you knew how to do this. That' why the hint was so short initially.

Comment: Having a good google-fu and previous experience in project-euler is always a good resource :)

Comment: @chubakueno As a plug, I'd encourage you to check out [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/), if you want to learn math.